# python считывание выражений из текстового файла и вычисление результата

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я новичок, ничего похожего не нашел.
Есть файл `calc.txt`, в котором хранятся записи вида

```
120 + 45
23 / 4
```

то есть `A + B`, разделённые пробелами.
Операнды — целые числа. Операции — арифметические (включая деление нацело и нахождение остатка).
Напишите программу, которая вычисляет все эти операции и находит сумму их результатов. Пропишите обработку возможных ошибок. Программа не должна завершаться при первой же ошибке, она учитывает все верные строки и выводит найденный ответ.

Я написал такой код, мне сказали eval использовать небезопасно, помогите исправить.

```py
with open('calc.txt') as file_data:
    result = 0
    for line in file_data:
        try:
            result += eval(line)
        except (SyntaxError, TypeError):
            pass
    print('Результат:', result)
```

Comment: --> **разделенные пробелами** <-- это написано не зря. Читаешь строку, делишь по пробелам ( ``split()`` ), получаешь список [число, операция, число]. Дальше в зависимости от операции выполняешь какое-то действие. PS. То, что целые числа, тоже не зря написано.

Comment: `120 + 45 23 / 4` - это у вас 2 строки или это все в одной строке?

Comment: У меня есть папка, посвященная этой теме, пример одного из скриптов: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/b73c2decdb363b57eaba1962362ce1733521d16d/calculator/use__ast_parse_eval.py :D  Но, похоже в вашем случае, не нужно что-то такое сложное, если у вас 2 числа и операция между ними на каждой строке

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть еще такой способ. Он сложнее в понимании, зато проще добавлять новые арефметические опрации.

```
#Создаем словарь с лямбда-функциями для каждого арефметического действия.
operators = {
    '+':lambda a, b: a + b,
    '-':lambda a, b: a - b,
    '*':lambda a, b: a * b,
    '/':lambda a, b: a / b,
}

with open('calc.txt') as file_data:
    result = 0
    for line in file_data:
        try:
            #Ищем арефметический знак в строке
            for i in operators:
                if i in line:
                    line = line.split(f' {i} ') #Разбиваем пример на два числа
                    result += operators[i](int(line[0]), int(line[1]))
                    break
        except (SyntaxError, TypeError):
            pass
    print('Результат:', result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Пойдет?

```
with open('calc.txt', 'r') as f:
    mass = []
    resault = []
    for i in f.readlines():
        mass.append(i.replace('\n', '').split())
    for i in mass:
        try:
            if i[1] == '+':
                resault.append(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} {i[2]} = ' + str(int(i[0]) + int(i[2])))
            elif i[1] == '-':
                resault.append(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} {i[2]} = ' + str(int(i[0]) - int(i[2])))
            elif i[1] == '/':
                resault.append(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} {i[2]} = ' + str(int(i[0]) / int(i[2])))
            elif i[1] == '*':
                resault.append(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} {i[2]} = ' + str(int(i[0]) * int(i[2])))
            elif i[1] == '%':
                resault.append(f'{i[0]} {i[1]} {i[2]} = ' + str(int(i[0]) % int(i[2])))
        except (IndexError, ZeroDivisionError, ValueError) as e:
            print(e)
    print('\nРезультаты:')
    for i in resault:
        print(i)
```

Тут я считываю с файла строку, и записываю её в массив(удаляя перенос на новую строку), и записываю строку в массив, далее просто сравниваю оператор, если оператор "+" я с первым и вторым числом произвожу соответственное действие

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так:

```
with open('calc') as file_data:
    result = 0
    for line in file_data:
        try:
            line = line.replace('\n', '')
            line_item = line.split(' ')
            if line_item[1] == '+':
                result = float(line_item[0])+float(line_item[2])
            elif line_item[1] == '-':
                result = float(line_item[0])-float(line_item[2])
            elif line_item[1] == '*':
                result = float(line_item[0])*float(line_item[2])
            elif line_item[1] == '/':
                result = float(line_item[0])/float(line_item[2])
            else:
                raise ('Знак не распознан')
            print('Результат {0}: {1}'.format(line, result))
        except:
            print('Результат {0}: {1}'.format(line, 'Ошибка'))
```

Comment: Величайше вам благодарен